# Join two datatables into with with a filter

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two datatables which I need to get merged into one.

DataTable1:

```
+-----+------------------+----------+
| id  |       user       |  userno  |
+-----+------------------+----------+
|   1 | test             | u0000123 |
|   2 | user1            | u0000124 |
| ... | ...              | ...      |
+-----+------------------+----------+
```

DataTable2:

```
+-------+----------+
|  id   |  userno  |
+-------+----------+
| 85000 | u0000123 |
| 85001 | u0000124 |
|   ... | ...      |
+-------+----------+
```

How would I be able to merge these two into one datatable with the condition that the row **userno** in datatable1 is the same as in datatable2. At the end it should look like that:

```
+-----+-------+----------+----------+
| id  | user  |  userno  | secondid |
+-----+-------+----------+----------+
|   1 | test  | u0000123 |    85000 |
|   2 | user1 | u0000124 |    85001 |
| ... | ...   | ...      |      ... |
+-----+-------+----------+----------+
```

I thought about using LINQ to solve it but I don't know if it possible to do it with that.

Comment: Couldn't you use a sql view to get the merged table directly from database ?

Comment: Sadly not as these datas come from two different databases on two different servers..

Comment: Then create a new DataTable. Iterate of both source DataTables find corresponding rows and move data over field by field into a new DataRow.

Comment: You can use federated tables to have both on them on the same database. Federated tables allow database A to connect database B and synchronize a table. 

Try this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-create-connection.html

If it helps you, i will post it as the answer.

Comment: @Issac411 sadly this won't work for me

Comment: @YongShun this one does seem to work. just gotta figure out how to tell it in which row to write the value ^^ but it does look promising

Comment: @YongShun I figured it out! Thanks for linking the other question.